# .htaccess Subdirectory Rewrite with Jekyll

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, blogs, jekyll

I have a small blog in generated with [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) up on a shared Apache server. I have been following [this guide](http://zacht.me/zacht/site/articles/Deploy-Jekyll-With-A-Github-Webhook/) to set up the server so that I can update the site by pushing changes via GitHub, but I haven't even gotten that far yet. The `.htaccess` rewrite rule to point the domain to the generated `/_site` subdirectory has me stumped. The code I'm using (below) is redirecting the site correctly, but the guides I've read say that this code should hide the subdirectory from the URL, and this is not happening. It works correctly on the homepage, but subpages still have `/_site/` in their URL. Any ideas?

#### [My website](http://joejoiner.tk)

#### .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?joejoiner.tk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_site/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?joejoiner.tk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ _site/index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a trailing `/` to the end of line 6 in the above code block, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_site/$1/
```